# Recover an OFDM signal affected by AWGN

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, noise, deconvolution, blind-deconvolution

I have an OFDM signal affected by AWGN, if I know the power of the gaussian noise, can I recover the OFDM signal? Can I perform deconvolution to recover the original signal?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when we can recover OFDM in fading scenarios along with gaussian noise, then yes we can also recover it in just gaussian noise. You can think of fading coefficients having a magnitude of 1 and phase zero

Comment: Hi, could you please give me a Matlab example, because I am not sure where to perform deconvolution operation, for the received time domain samples? or for constellation after FFT? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague for me.

I understand that you want to make a convolution on an received OFDM signal to synchronize right?

OFDM signal is demodulated through an FFT. Usually FFT size is a power of 2 (128,256,512,etc...). To demodulate FFT symbols cleanly, they must be synchronized (beginning symbol is found)

Your OFDM waveform has probably a preamble, you could use it to synchronize. Correlating  preamble sequence with received signal can be enough if there is no carrier frequency offset (in time domain).

If there is a carrier frequency offset, you could synchronize in frequency domain first.

This is quite an amount of work in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

AWGN is additive in nature by definition, so you won't need any deconvolution to estimate transmitted symbols.

Received samples are obtained as :
$$y[n] = x[n] + w[n]$$
where $w[n]$ are Complex Circular Symmetric White Gaussian Noise samples.

In OFDM receiver when you strip-off cyclic prefix and take FFT of the received samples, you get Freq-Domain vectors as follows:
$$Y[k] = X[k] + W[k]$$
where $Y[k]$ is the received complex soft symbol at $k^{th}$ subcarrier of OFDM system, and, $W[k]$ are FFT of $w[n]$, and since $w[n]$ are circular symmetric, hence, $W[k]$ will have the same properties as $w[n]$, meaning zero mean and same variance.

Now, you can estimate transmitted symbols $\hat X[k]$ from $Y[k]$ by applying minimum squared distance rule.

You can use the following MATLAB code to simulate this:

> % 256 Subcarrier OFDM system affected only by AWGN
>
> % Generate 512 random bits for 256 subcarriers
>
> data_bits = sign(rand(512, 1) - 0.5);
>
> qpsk_symbols = sqrt(2)*(data_bits(1:2:end) + 1j*data_bits(2:2:end));
>
> % Take IFFT to create time-domain samples
>
> x_n = ifft(qpsk_symbols, 256);
>
> % Add Cyclic Prefix of 16 samples
>
> x_n_cp = [x_n(end-15:end); x_n];
>
> % Add AWGN
>
> y_n_cp = awgn(x_n_cp, 26);
>
> figure(1);subplot(2,1,1);hold on;
>
> plot(real(x_n_cp));plot(real(y_n_cp));
>
> figure(1);subplot(2,1,2);hold on;
>
> plot(imag(x_n_cp));plot(imag(y_n_cp));
>
> % Remove Cyclic Prefix
>
> y_n = y_n_cp(17:end);
>
> Y_k = fft(y_n, 256);
>
> X_hat_k = sqrt(2) * (sign(real(Y_k)) + 1j*sign(imag(Y_k)));
>
> figure(2);hold on;
>
> stem(angle(qpsk_symbols)-angle(X_hat_k));

Figure(1) shows time-domain samples generated after IFFT operation at Transmitter compared to AWGN added samples. SubPlot(1) shows real part and SubPlot(2) shows imaginary part :
[image: ofdm_td_samples]

Figure(2) shows phase-difference between transmitted QPSK Symbols and estimated QPSK symbols. This is one way to see how many symbols are in error. In this particular plot 3 QPSK symbols are estimated in error, rest 253 are correctly estimated.
[image: QPSK SER]